# How to return text when nothing is found in array- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have managed to write the code of function for a js array of contacts:

```
function searchcontacts() {
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var inputcase = input.value.toUpperCase();
    for (i=0; i < contacts.length; i++){        
        if(contacts[i].name.indexOf(inputcase) != -1) {
            contacts[i].showcontact();
        } 
        else { 
            continue;
            document.write("no result found </br>"); 
        }
    }
}

function showcontact() {
    document.write("Name:"+this.name+"<br>");
    document.write("address:"+this.address+"<br>");
    document.write("email:"+this.email+"<br>");
    document.write("phone number:"+this.phone+"<hr>");
}

function Contact(name,address,email,phone) {
    this.name=name;
    this.address=address;
    this.email=email;
    this.phone=phone;
    this.showcontact=showcontact;
}
```

and now i'm trying to find a way to return the string "no result found " when nothing is found at all. Because continue; skips totaly this step. Does anyone know how can i do that? New at web developing!Thank you in advance!

Comment: The quickest would probably be to put continue after document.write...

Comment: add a counter for `results` and increment it each time you show a contact. After the loop, if results count is zero, then show no results message

Comment: A `continue` is like a `goto` so having code after it like you do does nothing.

Comment: i think the @baao is right, you should use continue after document.write

Comment: @baao: That won't work, because it would write "no result found" for each contact that doesn't match, and you would get a lot of "no result found" outputted along with matching contact records. Also, it's pointless having `continue` as the last statement in a loop, because it is going to continue the loop anyway at that point

Answer (score 2):

You need to track how many results you find and check that after the loop, something like this:

```
function searchcontacts() {
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var inputcase = input.value.toUpperCase();

    var results = 0;

    for (i=0; i < contacts.length; i++){        
        if(contacts[i].name.indexOf(inputcase) != -1) {
            contacts[i].showcontact();
            results++;
        }
    }

    if(results === 0){
        document.write("no result found </br>"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this worked!!! so easy and something that i had already learned! But i don't have the experience yet to combine the methods! thank you all so much for your time!